# Como alterar um atributo, javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando alterar o valor de um atributo mas aparentemente nada muda, veja o exemplo usado:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("stars").offsetTop); // me retorna 83
document.getElementById("stars").offsetTop = 10;
console.log(document.getElementById("stars").offsetTop); // continua retornando 83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu método usado como exemplo é que é o problema, o `offsetTop` é um método `get`, e não `set`. Ou seja, com ele você pode somente obter valores e não declará-los ou mudá-los. No caso como o `offsetTop` captura o `top` do elemento em questão (em pixels), o máximo que poderá fazer para alterá-lo é por meio de **css**:

```
document.getElementById("stars").style.top = valor
// O propriedade top só pode ser usada após a declaraçã o da propriedade position...
```

Mas você pode sim mudar os "atributos" por javascript, por exemplo com o método `scrollTop`. Veja nesse exemplo:

```
 console.log(document.getElementById("stars").scrollTop); // retornará 0
 document.getElementById("stars").scrollTop = 10;
 console.log(document.getElementById("stars").scrollTop); // retornará 10
```

O método `scrollTop` sim é um método `get/set`. Com ele ocê captura e determina valores.

### [Demonstração - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2d55twh/)

Comment: Obrigado por explicar, não sabia que tinha esse porque..